# Unable to Open KDE Software Properties

Tags: kubuntu, kde

## Problem

Everytime I run `software-properties-kde` I receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-kde", line 29, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'
```

## System Specifications

- KDE Plasma Version 5.12.9
- Kubuntu 18.04
- python2.7 and python3.7 installed
- python-pyqt5 (5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2)
- python3-pyqt5 (5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2)

Comment: Did you touched Python 3 parts of your system? Do you have anaconda installed? What is the output of `which python`, `which python3`?

Comment: Hi, @N0rbert I recall doing some changes in order to make jupyter notebooks work with both python2 and python3. Here are the outputs:
`/usr/bin/python`
`/usr/bin/python3`